# Saxon is throwing "Cannot use xsl:result-document to write to a destination already used for the principal output:"

Tags: xslt, saxon

This is my first question here so please don't beat me up to hard :)
I am using Apache Camel with Saxon XSLT transformer. And my goal is to output the results of an XSLT transformation into a file. I searched a lot but could not find any hints as to why I am getting that error.

This is my XSLT snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
            xmlns:core="http://interoperability.gc.ca/core/1.0"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi xsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="someE">
        <someE>
            <someA>aaaa</someA>
            <someB>bbbb</someB>
        </someE>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:result-document href="transformer.out" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$someE"/>
    <xsl:result-document/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where `$destinationAbsolutePath` is the absolute file path (`file:///C:/Temp/output.txt`) of the output file.

What am I missing ?

Update:
I ran the transformation from the command line and got the same failure:

```
C:\Temp\osfsa>java -jar Saxon-HE-9.9.1-7.jar -t -o:C:\Temp\osfsa\out\index.out -s:C:\Temp\osfsa\in\exporter.out -xsl:C:\Temp\osfsa\xml2fixedlength.xsl
Saxon-HE 9.9.1.7J from Saxonica
Java version 11.0.13
Stylesheet compilation time: 1.1386491s (1138.6491ms)
Processing file:/C:/Temp/osfsa/in/exporter.out
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Building tree for file:/C:/Temp/osfsa/in/exporter.out using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 12.0011ms
Tree size: 62 nodes, 157 characters, 9 attributes
Writing to file:/C:/Temp/osfsa/out/transformer.out
Error in xsl:result-document/@href on line 18 column 112 of xml2fixedlength.xsl:
XTDE1490: Cannot use xsl:result-document to write to a destination already used for the
principal output: file:/C:/Temp/osfsa/xml2fixedlength.xsl
In template rule with match="/" on line 11 of xml2fixedlength.xsl
Cannot use xsl:result-document to write to a destination already used for the principal output: file:/C:/Temp/osfsa/xml2fixedlength.xsl
```

Comment: Can't tell from what you've shown, but is `$destinationAbsolutePath` pointing to the transformation's output file? You can't write to the same file from two places.

Comment: Where does Apache Camel store the primary or principal output? Does that template you have generate any other output below or before the `xsl:result-document`?

Comment: Also, is `<xsl:result-document href="{$destinationAbsolutePath}" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>` really as shown? Normally the content you want to output goes inside of the `xsl:result-document` element, with an empty element you are creating an empty file, is that what you have or want?

Comment: @JimGarrison I only have one transformation that writes to that file. Well, attempts to write. I can see the file being created but it is blank and it throws the error.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am not sure that Camel even aware of the principal output. Also, the template doesn't generate any other output.

Comment: Start testing whether running your XSLT and XML through the Saxon command line works fine. If that does work as intended then try to figure which Camel version you use and which Saxon version it uses and add that info. Then hopefully someone with insight into the integration of Saxon into Camel can tell where the error comes from.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I will definitely try that. At the same time, is there a good example of invoking XSLT transformation using pure Java ? And, of course, for Saxon. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, there is the documentation detailing it https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/using-xsl/embedding/ and the resources download contains Java samples. Also online at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/samples/java/he/S9APIExamples.java

Comment: @MartinHonnen I ran it from command line and got the same error. Please see the update in the main question.

Comment: Please provide minimal but complete details to allow anyone to reproduce the problem. So show a minimal but complete stylesheet including the parameter binding for that `$destinationAbsolutePath`. And my understanding of Saxon's command option is that you need the `-o` option if your stylesheet produces content outside of `xsl:result-document` and you want that to be stored in a file (and not have it written to the console). So to test whether your `xsl:result-document` works, I would not expect you to provide the `-o` option.

Answer (score 2):

You've obviously simplified your code for demonstration purposes (we can tell because it's not well-formed, and because the error message refers to line 27), which is fine in principle, except that I think you've removed something critical to the error.

Here's an example that will give you the error. If you run a transformation with `file:///out.xml` as the principal output destination (specified when the transformation is invoked), and the transformation then does:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  xxx
  <xsl:result-document href="file:///out.xml">
     yyy
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

then you will get this error. The key ingredients are

(a) the `href` value on `xsl:result-document` is the same URI (after absolutisation) as the principal output URI

(b) some output has already been written (`'xxx'` in this example) when `xsl:result-document` is evaluated.

I hope this helps you resolve it. If not, you need to give us more details of exactly what you are running and how.

**Update**

There's something a little bit strange here, which is that the URI appearing in the error message is the URI of the stylesheet; I would expect it to be the output URI. That might just be poor diagnostics, I will check.

**Further Update**

Your code contains two `xsl:result-document` instructions, both empty:

```
<xsl:result-document href="transformer.out" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="$someE"/>
<xsl:result-document/>
```

You presumably intended to write a single instruction, with xsl:copy-of as its content:

```
<xsl:result-document href="transformer.out" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8">
   <xsl:copy-of select="$someE"/>
</xsl:result-document>
```

The second `xsl:result-document` instruction has no @href attribute, so it defaults to writing to the principal output; but the `xsl:copy-of` instruction has already written to the principal output.

Now I need to understand why the wrong URI appears in the error message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I updated my question with the real xslt transformation that I am testing.
It is still failing :(

Comment: OK, thanks, with your stylesheet I've reproduced the problem (under SaxonJ 11, not yet released). Investigating.

Comment: This a good bad news :) 
At least now I know that I wasn't doing anything wrong.
Thank you for your help! I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: OMG! This is embarrassing. That's why I don't like auto-completion features.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @mowglim, which tool autocompletes that `xsl:result-document` as an empty element?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I use IntelliJ. I have no idea how it would do that.